# are global variables a good idea for a flask website application?

Tags: python, postgresql, jinja2

There is a flask website which accesses some data stored in a database. The data is related to more than one templates of the website, and I would prefer the database not to be accessed again and again for the same info as the user is visiting the website templates, but rather to be stored in variables. Session is not a good idea because of the size of the data. I'm wondering if using global variables for that purpose would be a good idea. Accessing once the database and assigning the data to the global variables, from where it will be available through the templates of the website for as long as the session will last. I would be grateful to know if this is the proper way to achieve it, or there are drawbacks in a way that accessing the database several times if needed, would be a better option. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Global variables are almost always a terrible idea for a multitude of reasons, but in this case it's inadvertent sharing of data between unrelated requests.

Comment: The data is distributed between the available requests, sometimes the data is relevant with more than one request. So you are saying that accessing the database more frequently is better than using global variables.

Comment: Most ORM type systems deal with all of this for you, it's not your concern, but internally they do this with database connection pools to keep your database access as efficient as possible.

Comment: Thank you, I'm going to see how they works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your code is not using sqlalchemy and you do not want to do the heavy lifting of refatoring the code for various reasons then you could wrap you database access code in to a class and attach it to the flask app instance.

```
app.db = DBAccessClass()
```

In then through the code you's call on the instance attached to the flask app.
This wont solve your issue with making multiple calls to DB for the same data that can be cached.

Then you can use an annotation class that would implement a caching strategy for your DBAccessClass, here is a very simple example:

```
from functools import wraps, update_wrapper


class cache(object):


    def __init__(self):
        self.named_caches = {}


    def __call__(self, f):

        @wraps(f)
        def decorated(*args, **kwargs):
            key = f.__name__
            if key not in self.named_caches:
                self.named_caches[key] = f(*args, **kwargs)
            return self.named_caches[key]

        return update_wrapper(decorated, f)


cached = cache()


class MyDBAccessClass(object):

    @cached
    def get_some_data(self):
       data = query_db()
       return data
```

This might be a short term solution, would strongly encourage to consider sQLAlchemy.

Comment: Thank you. My level of understanding in Python didn't help me much to adapt your example into my code. However I searched for a solution relative to caching, and I came up with cachetools, which solved that issue for the time.

Comment: yes cachetools would help achieve what I have described above, but pay attention to the docs where cachetools has the following:
`As with cached(), the context manager obtained by calling lock(self) will only guard access to the cache itself. It is the user’s responsibility to handle concurrent calls to the underlying wrapped method in a multithreaded environment.`

So if you want a fully atomic cached function call, you might endup using my code as a starting point where you'd use a lock to synchronize cache access and wrapped function call.

Answer (score 1):

Try with ORM tools like sQLAlchemy, it does most of the heavy weight lifting for you.

https://www.sqlalchemy.org/

Examples available here

https://realpython.com/flask-by-example-part-2-postgres-sqlalchemy-and-alembic/

Comment: Thank you. I'm going to read the documentation you posted and see how it can be useful in this, or any other case.

Comment: Thank you very much. I guess this is going to be the solution in the long term, that offers also many other advantages. However I need time to get familiar with it.